# Copy Kodachi default desktop settings including pre installed programs to a new sudo user

Tags: linux, home, settings

I am new with linux, I started using Kodachi and so far I like it, I had to create a new sudo user for the ssl keys, but when I logged into to this new user none of the preinstalled settings and programs are there.

Is there any way move this settings to the new user created?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is a "sudo user"? how do you log into that? Why do you need one "for SSL keys"? and what does "for SSL keys" mean? Whichever user you used to add a new user could have also done everything a user with sudo privileges can do, so this all makes no sense!

Comment: @MarcusMüller https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-sudo-user-manage-sudo-access-on-ubuntu-20-04 and  https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/difference-between-sudo-su